# Text is resized wrong on mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've got a pretty weird problem on my website and was wondering if any of you know how to fix it. The problem is as follows:
On the website (typez.bplaced.net) I have several pages that look like I want them to on mobile, for example all the [Leaderboards](http://typez.bplaced.net/edh/leaderboard_players.php) which you have access to as a guest and several other when logged in.
But for some strange reason the "[News](http://typez.bplaced.net/news.php)" and "About" (can't post more links) have way too huge text when you compare it to text on the other pages... it just doesn't look good and isn't readable at all.

Here's the php code:

```
require_once("./lib/config_data.php");
require_once("./lib/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php");
include("navbar.php");

$tpl = new Smarty;
$tpl->display("./templates/news_head.tpl");

$directory = "./news/";
$i = 0;

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $file) {
if($file->isDot()) continue;
$filename = $file->getFilename();
$myfile = fopen($directory.$filename, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$text = fread($myfile,filesize($directory.$filename));
$date = str_replace("-", ".", substr($filename, 0, 10));

$news_array[strtotime($date)]["text"] = $text;
$news_array[strtotime($date)]["date"] = $date;

fclose($myfile);
}

krsort($news_array);

$n = 1;
foreach ($news_array as $news)
{
if($n <= 4)
{
    $tpl->assign("DATE", $news["date"]);
    $tpl->assign("TEXT", $news["text"]);
    $tpl->display("./templates/news_article.tpl");
    $n++;
}
}


$tpl->display("./templates/news_footer.tpl");
```

My template:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>News</title>
<!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/main.css">
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
<main>
<h3>News</h3>
```

--end head

```
{$DATE}:
<p>{$TEXT}</p>
<br/>
```

-- end article

```
</main>
</body
</html>
```

--end footer

I've tried using the view-port tag but since the rest of the website is also sporting that "zoomed out" style (because I wouldn't be able to fit the tables on a normal phone screen) I don't like using it. Also since those two are the only two sites that don't have tables in them I tried adding some "dummy-tables" to see if it would scale the text-size correctly then but no success there either.
What am I missing here? Thanks for the help in advance

SP

Comment: Not sure what the php / smarty angle is here, this sounds more like a css question.

Comment: Just use mediaqueries to lower the `font-size`

Comment: I'm using "@media screen and (max-width: 960px)" but it doesn't apply it...

Comment: You are only resetting the right padding in your [mediaqueries](https://imgur.com/dJaSvCq)

Comment: Currently yes, but it's not working if I add font-size either way... the padding part isn't working either as you can see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for my specific problem myself:

In a previous attempt to fix the styling I had used the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

tag in order to get the site to behave predictable... My problem then was that the "zoomed out" look got lost and I needed that because I had tables on other pages that required the screen to be quite large (=> zoomed out on mobile).

What I didn't realize back then was that I could tinker with the initial-scale variable to get what I wanted... I ended up with this on all my pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.39">
```

and a few minor changes to my css later my website looks like I want it to when viewed on mobile. Yes, it is not the prettiest out there but it is consistent and usable. :)